# Xcode Auto Layout not respecting constraints as expected

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm new to Auto Layout so this probably has a very simple solution. In the image below, I have a simple label and three constraints applied to it (these were generated by choosing 'Reset to Suggested Constraints'):
[image: Xcode interface builder]

When I try to simulate above scene in a simulator (iPhone 6 Plus), it looks like this:
[image: Simulator]

In the simulator, why is the label closer to the right edge of the screen while in the interface builder, it's closer to the left? In other words, how do I need to modify the constraints in order to have the label display in the simulator as it appears in the interface builder?

Thanks!

Comment: The question is why you expected it to be closer to the left? There are zillions of valid ways to constrain views. Maintaining absolute distance from one edge or the other. Maintaining proportional distance. Etc. If you want a particular behavior, you have to think hard to formalize what it is that you want and then express that through carefully chosen constraints. It's improbable that Xcode will guess the thing you have in mind. It doesn't read minds.

Comment: Regarding "have the label display in the simulator as it appears in the interface builder", that's literally impossible. That's because the canvas in Interface Builder has different proportions from the simulator window. So something has to change between the two. In this case it was the distance between the right edge and the label (because there's no constraint making that distance the same). For some reason, you don't acknowledge that the distance from the left edge, which is what is constrained, is in fact the same, as it should be. To you, the one is important and the other invisible.

Comment: @KenThomases If I add a constraint to the right edge as well, the label disappears off the screen. I'm guessing it's my obliviousness to understanding how Auto Layout is working in this case that's causing issues. If you wanted the label to appear closer to the left-bottom corner, how would you go about to define the constraints?

Comment: I think I'm getting it more now. Auto Layout can be confusing! Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you add a constraint to both the right and left edges, then the label can be no wider than the width of the window minus the distances from the edges. So, shrinking the window shrinks the label, possibly to zero width. If the window is small enough, the width will be negative, which is illegal and generate an unsatisfiable constraints exception, and some constraint(s) will be ignored. In most cases, you want to specify two constraints in each orientation *including any intrinsic size*. Since a label has intrinsic width based on content, you want only one additional horizontal constraint.